# How to map two columns of same value in neo4j

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, relationship, hierarchy

```
MATCH (a:Employee.ID),(b:Employee.MANAGER_ID)
CREATE (a)-[r:RELATED]->(b)
RETURN r
```

I am new to neo4j and i have no idea how to map two columns in neo4j
My data looks like this

I want to relate 1 to 2 as 1 is manager of 2
Similarly i want to relate 3 to 2 and so on
Basically i wan't to map the id to manager id

```
1->2->3->4
```

I tried this but it shows error

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input '.': expected an identifier character, whitespace, NodeLabel, a property map, ')' or a relationship pattern (line 1, column 16 (offset: 15))
>   "MATCH (a:Police.PID),(b:Police.MANAGER)"

It showed error. Now i don't know what should be the correct code.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect for matching/selection of Employee nodes.

The following query should do the expected:

```
MATCH (manager:Employee),(employee:Employee)
WHERE manager.ID=employee.MANAGER_ID
CREATE (manager)-[r:RELATED]->(employee)
RETURN count(r) as rels_added
```

*Make the changes if required*